# Binding selected row to new data row and using import row VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row, datarow, datarowview

I am binding a selected row to a new data row which needs to be added to a database.

I am using the dt.Importrow(newRow) to add the new datarow to the data table.

However, if I make changes to this new row, it also changes the selected row.

code below

```
'''             Dim original_Row As DataRow
                Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow   
original_Row = CType(DataTbale.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row 

                newRow = original_Row
```

newRow("Name") = John 'Changing value to new row here

```
                dt.ImportRow(newRow)'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you actually want to do is create a new row for a `DataTable`, copy data from the currently selected row, modify that data, then add the row to the table.

Firstly, you should be binding your `DataTable` via a `BindingSource` and getting the selection from that:

```vb
'Get the current row.
Dim currentRow = DirectCast(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row

'Create a new row.
Dim newRow = myDataTable.NewRow()

'Copy existing data to new row.
newRow.ItemArray = currentRow.ItemArray

'Edit data.
newRow("Name") = "John"

'Add new row to table.
myDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
```